# Create a LookUp Column using SPServices "UpdateList" operation

Tags: jquery, lookup-column, spservices

I want to dynamically add a new list ("AddList" operation), and then use the SPServices "UpdateList" operation to add "newFields". I was able to get the "Text" fields to add properly, but the LookUp fields are what I'm specifically having trouble with.

Here's my code:

```
var newListName = "Title" + todaysDate;    
var nfields = "<Fields><Method ID='1'><Field Type='LookUp' List='{4E185F24-9DE1-4E2F-8915-16C28816F102}' ShowField='ID' DisplayName='MatchedEquipmentRecord'></Field></Method>" +
            "<Method ID='2'><Field Type='LookUp' List='"+ listGUID +"' ShowField='ID' DisplayName='OriginalSupplyRecord'></Field></Method>" +
            "<Method ID='3'><Field Type='Text' DisplayName='AccountCustodian' ResultsType='Text'></Field></Method>" + 
            "<Method ID='4'><Field Type='Text' DisplayName='AssetID' ResultsType='Text'></Field></Method>" + 
            "<Method ID='5'><Field Type='Text' DisplayName='SerialNumber' ResultsType='Text'></Field></Method>" + 
            "<Method ID='6'><Field Type='Text' DisplayName='ItemDescription' ResultsType='Text'></Field></Method>" + 
            "<Method ID='7'><Field Type='Text' DisplayName='Brand' ResultsType='Text'></Field></Method>" + 
            "<Method ID='8'><Field Type='Text' DisplayName='ModelNumber' ResultsType='Text'></Field></Method>" + 
          "</Fields>"; 
$().SPServices({ 
    operation: 'UpdateList', 
        listName: newListName, 
        newFields: nfields, 
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) { 
           console.log(xData.responseText);
        }
});
```

My variables todaysDate and listGUID I've made previously.

When I log the responseText, I get this error message for my Lookup columns:

```
<ErrorCode>0x80004005</ErrorCode><ErrorText>Operation Failed</ErrorText>
```

I'm assuming it has to do with the properties in the `"Field Type='LookUp'"` that is giving me the issue. I've searched all over the internet all morning to try and get the right names for the what I need to reference in the method. But I couldn't find anything that I needed.

Does anyone know what is required to dynamically create a lookup column with SPServices "UpdateList" operation?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Type='Lookup'` with a lowercase U